# JList - Retrieve item

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am stuck with Jlist and never thought that Jlist can be that complicated.

With a left mouse click on Jlist item I want to do some action. I know that i need action listener but I was not able to get it work.

In my specific case there are saved paths to .sql files in JList. When I click on item in JList I want to read from that file and save it to JTextArea.

Maybe I am putting listener on wrong place in code? Or I am coding wrong?

Model Name = model

JList Name = SQLScriptList

Jtextarea Name = SQLEditor

With this code I tried to save item from the list in specific label or textbox just to see if action work.

```
 //Copy from LIST to TextArea
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {

                String selectedItem = (String) SQLScriptList.getSelectedValue();
                // add selectedItem to your second list.
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) SQLScriptList.getModel();
                if (model == null) {
                    //model = new DefaultListModel();
                    SQLScriptList.setModel(model);
                }
                model.addElement(selectedItem);

            }
            SQLScriptList.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }
        //list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    };
```

---

## Solved

Here is solution that worked in my case:

```
private void SQLScriptListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    JList list = (JList) evt.getSource();
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint()); //GET INDEX 0,1,2,3

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(files[index]);
            SQLEditor.read(reader, files[index]); //Object of JTextArea
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use a `MouseListener`, you use a `ListSelectionListener`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: daniu is absolutly right! Additionally you need to register the Listener outside of your Clicked event. (The event will never be triggered, because it is not registered, unless it is triggered -> will never happen... you see what I mean?)
For a basic scenario register the listener, after the JList has been constructed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Hansa

Yeah I've tried to put event in many places in code but regardless it has been never triggered out. 
Anyway thank You both daniu and Hansa, I'll try with ListSelectionListener to get it work.

Comment: @Jskako, `Here is solution that worked in my case:` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer that directed you to the solution by clicking on the checkmark so that people know the problem has been solved. You have not accepted answers from any of your questions in the forum.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on item in JList I want to read from that file and save it to JTextArea.

Normally this is not done on a single mouse click.

Typically the Action is invoked when the user:

1. uses the Enter key, or
2. double clicks on the item

For this type of processing check out [List Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) which allows you to provide an `Action` to be invoked in either of the above situations.

Otherwise you should use a `MouseListener`, not a ListSelectionListener as suggested in the comments above, since the user should be able to navigate through the items in the list using the down/up arrow keys without causing the action to be invoked. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for working examples.